# How to find the correct selector in order to type in a text

Tags: css-selectors, puppeteer

I am trying to add a text (lorem ipsum...) to the description section in a webpage, the description section is like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="DescriptionJson" name="DescriptionJson" type="hidden" value="{&quot;time&quot;:1613133102434,&quot;blocks&quot;:[],&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2.18.0&quot;}">

    <label for="DescriptionJson_editor">Description</label>
    <div id="DescriptionJson_editor" class="border rounded" style="padding: 0.5rem 1.0rem;"><div class="codex-editor codex-editor--empty"><div class="codex-editor__redactor" style="padding-bottom: 300px;"><div class="ce-block ce-block--focused"><div class="ce-block__content"><div class="ce-paragraph cdx-block" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder=""></div></div></div></div><div hidden="" style="display: none;"><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
```

these are the selectors I have already tried:

- await page.type('input[name="DescriptionJson"]', 'lorem ipsum...');
- await page.type('#DescriptionJson_editor div[contenteditable="true"]', 'Lorem ipsum...')
- await page.type(
  '#DescriptionJson_editor',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
- await page.type(
  'body > div.container > main > form > div:nth-child(8)', 'Lorem ipsum...')

and every time I got this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector:"
Does anyone have any idea how to add this text to this "Description" section ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for my own question:

first it need a click and then typing is possible. Maybe this answer can help somebody...

```
await page.focus('#DescriptionJson_editor');
await page.click('#DescriptionJson_editor')

await page.type( '#DescriptionJson_editor', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
```